# Schedule task on the first workday of the month

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I've currently got a task that collects usage statistics from my website and is set to automatically email them to the client.

The problem is that the 1st of the month may be a non-work day which I guess is not a disaster but looks a bit unprofessional.

This is how I've scheduled it currently:

```
$schedule
    ->command("report", [ "--email" => "example@example.com" ]) //My command which accepts the email as a parameter
    ->monthly();
```

I was thinking of doing the following:

```
$schedule
    ->command("report", [ "--email" => "example@example.com" ]) //My command which accepts the email as a parameter
    ->monthlyOn(1)
    ->when(function () {
         if (in_array(Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek,[Carbon::SATURDAY,Carbon::SUNDAY])) { 
            return false;  
        }
        return true;
    });

$schedule
    ->command("report", [ "--email" => "example@example.com" ]) //My command which accepts the email as a parameter
    ->monthlyOn(2)
    ->when(function () {
         if (Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek == Carbon::MONDAY) { 
            return true; //1st was in the weekend
        }
        return false;
    });    

$schedule
    ->command("report", [ "--email" => "example@example.com" ]) //My command which accepts the email as a parameter
    ->monthlyOn(3)
    ->when(function () {
         if (Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek == Carbon::MONDAY) { 
            return true; //1st and 2nd was in the weekend
        }
        return false;
    });
```

However this looks like a very strange thing to do for something as simple as that.

So my questions:

1. If a `when` condition fails, does the task get attempted again until it succeeds? (Assuming this is a no but not sure)
2. Is there a simpler way to run a task on the first work-day of the month?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to run a cron job and then within the cron script ensure the day = Monday to then display it? Therefore the cron would run on the first day of every month but display on the monday?

Comment: @Option The problem is that when the cron finishes it sends an email. I don't know how to hold off on sending the email until Monday from within the cronjob. Unless you mean I should schedule it daily but also check if it's the first workday of the month in the cronjob?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/428807/run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-monday-of-every-month hopefully this will help as it's basically doing what you're looking for

Comment: Ideally I'd want something that I could code in my Laravel scheduler but if that's not possible then this is probably the way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: There is a better way i think if you want send the email in the first Monday of the month :) like this `$schedule
    ->command("report", [ "--email" => "example@example.com" ])
    ->mondays()->when(function () {
        return Carbon::now()->day <= 7;
    });` If you run this command every on monday, it should mean that it runs only on the first Monday of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post this as a community wiki answer for others to utilise if they ever need to in the future:

> You can put the condition into the actual crontab command:

```
[ "$(date '+%a')" = "Mon" ] && echo "It's Monday"
```

> Now, if this
>   condition is true on one of the first seven days in a month, you have
>   its first Monday. Note that in the crontab, the percent-syntax needs
>   to be escaped though:

```
0   12  1-7 *   *   [ "$(date '+\%a')" = "Mon" ] && echo "It's Monday"
```

the above is referenced from: https://superuser.com/questions/428807/run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-monday-of-every-month

This way it's set to a cronjob which will only run once per month on the Monday. I believe this will be your most effective method to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I know the accepted answer is correct but, there are always different ways I prefer this:

```
->monthlyOn(Carbon::parse('first monday of this month')->format('d'), '5:00')
```